# fancybox2 ajax request aborted

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using fancybox to open a php page with a form. My code is:

```
$('#new').fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    autoSize : true,
    padding: 5,
    autoResize:true
});
```

The code works fine and the content page opens but when I check firebug I see that the destination page is called several times and each time firebugs tells me the request is aborted before rendering the page. I have tried to google a bit but with no luck.

I am using jquery 1.9.1 and fancybox 2.1.5. Any idea on why?

Thanks a lot

Lelio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved with a bit of luck... Posting here for anyone who could need it.

The fancybox call was not in the document.ready function.

Moving it to the dom ready function solved the issue.

L